# Software to print PDF to booklet with scaling

Tags: pdf, printing

I have an OKI C911 printer that can do duplex printing up to SRA3.  I often want to print PDFs that have a smaller page size (e.g. A4 or smaller).

Adobe Acrobat Reader allows either setting scaling, or choosing to print a booklet but not both

Does anyone know of any PDF print management software that would allow printing to booklet, and allow me to scale at the same time.  I've also tried printing back to PDF at a different size, but there's no option for SRA4 as target size for Microsoft Print to PDF.

Thanks

Comment: Is a paid solution ok, or you want a free software?

Answer (score 1):

If you still haven’t found a good way to do this, you could try the free evaluation of [LEADTOOLS ePrint printer driver](https://www.eprintdriver.com/Download) (Disclaimer: I work for the vendors of ePrint). The driver installs like any regular Windows printer and accepts print jobs from Windows applications including Adobe Acrobat Reader. It can then re-direct the printout to your OKI printer.

When you select an output printer for the redirection, you can specify advanced settings using the [Enhanced Printing Options Dialog](https://www.eprintdriver.com/help/v6.0/Professional-Edition/EnhancedPrintingOptionsDialog.htm). Among these settings is the Layout option, which allows you to specify values like Single, Booklet, Double, up to 16X. Although the settings don’t contain a “resize” or “scale” option, you can use the scaling option when printing from Acrobat Reader itself and send the print job to ePrint to re-format as Booklet.

If you try that and don’t get the results you want, you can contact the support email address for free (ePrintSupport@leadtools.com), or you can simply un-install the evaluation to remove ePrint.